# How to say a variable doesn't contain a string in an Oracle DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am new to database. I am trying to say that a variable doesn't contain a string. Right now i have `"AND c.short_name != 'bic' " +` which only checks to see if it is not equal (obviously). Is there an sql command that searches the result for a string and returns `true` or `false`?

Sorry about the naiev-ness of this question,  but I'm still learning database in general. Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm

Comment: Do you mean like is it NULL?

Comment: @Mike No. The 'bic' represents a certain type of data that does not correspond with the item I am trying to pull. There are also variations of this tag which point to the same type data, 'bic_hghgj' for example is not warranted. And instead of searching each variance, anything with the string 'bic', therefore is undesirable for this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want to use `LIKE` and the `%` wildcard. examples are:

```
AND nvl(c.short_name,'N/A') NOT LIKE '%bic%' -- short_name does not contain 'bic'

AND nvl(c.short_name,'N/A') NOT LIKE 'bic%' -- short_name does not begin with 'bic'

AND nvl(c.short_name,'N/A') NOT LIKE '%bic' -- short_name does not end with 'bic'
```

Comment: You've forgotten to check for `NULL` value